# Refresh currently logged in user information

Tags: community, user, login

We have a fairly customized Salesforce Community, to say the least. We allow certain actions to take place, and some of those actions change the current user's profile from a lower level profile to a higher level one. These are custom profiles we have created.

I'm able to update the profile of the user, but I somehow need to reload/refresh the current user so that page variations etc display based on their newly acquired profile.

Does anyone know how I can do this from apex or from within the lightning component the user is interacting with at the time? Doing a page reload doesn't get me there. Currently the only way it seems to reload the user's information is to logout and log back in, but I'd like to not force them to do that if possible. Any thoughts on how I could achieve this?

Comment: Currently where do you update the profile from? is it a standard page or custom vf page or lighnting component?

Comment: If it is a custom vf page or lightning component, plz post the code which you have written for page redirect

Comment: It is a trigger than initiates the process and uses a future method to perform a callout. I'm not sure why I'd need to post the code for that.

Answer (score 0):

Future methods are asynchronous so by the time you initiated a page refresh , the asynchronous method might not be completed.

A possible solution could be to move the profile update operation from "trigger/future-method" into a "lightning component & associated JS/Apex controllers".

JavaScript in lightning components allows for callback, so you can run the page refresh action once the callback method is invoked.